# Multiple where statement returning undesired result

Tags: sql, oracle, rdbms

I'm trying to retrieve employees within depts 10 and 30 with a salary greater than 1500. This is the statement I'm running.

```
select ename, sal
from emp
where deptno = 10
or deptno = 30
and sal > 1500;
```

It returns:

```
Name               Salary
---------- --------------
NAME1                1600
NAME2                2850
NAME3                2450
NAME4                5000
NAME5                1300
```

When I run the query without the OR for only one dept, it returns NAME1 and NAME2, when I run it for the other dept it returns NAME3 and NAME4.

My question is, is it the OR statement that's giving me the incorrect NAME5? To me that query should work, I tried using AND instead of OR and it gives me no results. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AND` has precedence over `OR` in a SQL `WHERE` clause, so what you have is equivalent to

```
where deptno = 10 or (deptno = 30 and sal > 1500)
```

Try putting parentheses around the `OR` to see if it gives you the results you expect.

```
where (deptno = 10 or deptno = 30) and sal > 1500
```

(Also, it would clarify things a little bit if you included the department number in your `SELECT` so you can see which department each row is coming from.)

Comment: Thank you, that was it. I'm working with sql plus with an Oracle database, and I wasn't sure if the syntax was the same as working with sql server management studio... I guess I could have tested it, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the lack of parentheses.  But really the best way to write the query uses `in`:

```
select ename, sal
from emp
where deptno in (10, 30) and
      sal > 1500;
```

Comment: I did some reading on SQL syntax and I ended up doing exactly that. Also in some of my queries the 'IN' clause gave me more accurate results. Thanks for your input! :)